# The differential equation $ y y '' - ( y ' ) ^ 2 = - y ^ 2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ y $ is a function defined on $ \mathbb R $, twice differentiable such that $ y ( 0 ) = 1 $, $ y ' ( 0 ) = 0 $ and
$$ y y '' - ( y ' ) ^ 2 = - y ^ 2 \text . \tag E \label E $$
**(Be aware of the domain of $ y $ while considering any operation.)**

Any particular way to solve \eqref{E}? Do we have to consider a change of variable, because approximating the graph of $ f $ shows an exponential behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$X = \inf\{x >0 | y(x) = 0 \}$$
(if $y$ is never $0$ then $X = \infty$). Due to the continuity of $y$ and the fact that $y(0) = 1 > 0$, we have that $X > 0$. Hence, $y$ is strictly positive on $[0, X)$ and we can consider
$$ S(x) = \log(y(x)). $$
By replacing $y = e^S$ on the differential equation we obtain
$$ e^{2S(x)} S''(x) + e^{2S(x)}(S'(x))^2 - e^{2S(x)}(S'(x))^2 = - e^{2S(x)},$$
and simplifying we obtain
$$ S''(x) = -1, $$
together with the initial conditions
$$ S(0) = S'(0) = 0.$$
Therefore the solution is given by
$$ S(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2}, x\in [0,X) \Rightarrow y(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}, x\in [0,X)$$
From this we see that in fact $X = +\infty$, so the formula works for all positive reals. A similar argument can be use to show that the same is true on the entire real line.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from quotient rule,

$$ yy'' - (y')^2 = y^2 \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)' $$

so that

$$yy'' - (y')^2 = y^2 \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)' = -y^2 $$

and so

$$\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)' = -1.$$

Note that $\frac{y'}{y} = \log(|y|)'$, giving

$$\log(|y|)'' = -1$$

which is easily solved and gives $y(x) = A e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. So whenever $y \neq 0$, the solution is

---

So we now know that $Ae^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is a solution. Let's suppose then that $y(x) = g(x) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. There is no harm in this assumption since $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is nonzero everywhere. For such a choice of $y$,

\begin{align}
y'(x) &= g'(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} - xg(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \\
y''(x) &= g''(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} -2xg'(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} - g(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} + x^2 g(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
\end{align}

Plugging into the differential equation and dividing through by $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ (which again is fine since it is nonzero) yields

$$ g(x)(g''(x) - 2xg'(x) - g(x) + x^2 g(x)) - (g'(x) - xg(x))^2 = -g(x)^2. $$

Or equivalently

$$ g(x)g''(x) - \color{red}{2xg(x)g'(x)} - \color{orange}{g(x)^2} + \color{blue}{x^2 g(x)^2} - \color{blue}{x^2 g(x)^2} + \color{red}{2xg(x)g'(x)} - g'(x)^2 = - \color{orange}{g(x)^2}.$$

Several terms cancel (paired up by color) leaving us only with

$$ gg'' = (g')^2. $$

We will show that $g$ must be positive. Since $g(0) = 1$ and $g'(0) = 0$, $g''(0) = 0$. The only way for $g$ to become negative is for $g'$ to be negative. Let $a$ be such that $g(a) = 0$. For simplicity, assume that $g'$ is negative immediately away from $0$ (else $g$ just becomes more positive before becoming negative). However $g''$ must be positive by the differential equation. By the mean value theorem,

$$ 0 < g''(c) = \frac{g'(a) - g'(0)}{a-0} = \frac{g'(a)}{a} < 0 $$

which is a contradiction. Thus $g$ must be positive. Since $y(x) = g(x) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and $g > 0$, $y > 0$ everywhere, justifying the division by $y$.

Comment: We need to prove that $y(x) \neq 0. \forall x,$ to divide by $y$

Comment: So you solve it on $\{x,y(x) \neq 0\},$ it remains to prove $\{x,y(x) \neq 0\} = \mathbb{R}$ to obtain a solution on $\mathbb{R}$ (not only where $y$ is nonzero), right?

Comment: Ah whoops accidentally deleted my comment, but yes. I'm working on a solution which is perhaps a little more accessible for a regular differential equations class.

Comment: @john Added details!

Answer (score 1):

By dividing with $y^2\neq 0$ we get $\frac{yy''-(y')^2}{y^2}=-1$, which is equivalent with $(\frac{y'}{y})'=-1$. Therefore, by integrating is $\frac{y'}{y}=-x+C$ and $y'+(x-C)y=0$. This is linear differential equation, which can be solved by integrating factor $e^{\int x-C dx}=e^\frac{x^2}{2}e^{-Cx}$:

$(ye^{\frac{x^2}{2}-Cx})'=0$

$y=De^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+Cx}$.

Now, initial conditions give
y(0)=1 and $y'(0)=0$ or $D=1$ and $C=0$.

Final solution is $y=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Comment: We need to prove that $y(x) \neq 0. \forall x,$ to divide by $y$

Answer (score 0):

$$yy''-(y')^2=-y^2 $$
$$\left (\dfrac {y'}{y}\right)'=-1$$
$$(\ln y)''=-1$$

$y=0$ satisfy the ODE but not the initial condition $y(0)=1$.

Comment: We need to justify the division by $y$ (why $y$ is nonzero)

Comment: $y=0$ satisfy the DE but not the initial condition $y(0)=1$ @john

Comment: Because zero function doesn’t satisfy initial conditions.

Comment: In this case $y \neq 0$ in other word there exists $x>0$ such that $y(x) \neq 0,$ maybe we can solve it on a neighborhood of $0,$ but we still need to prove that $y(x) \neq 0$ every where: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, y(x) \neq 0$